# Use end of URL as variable, without it being a GET parameter?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi, webapp2

I have some urls that match:

```
(r'foo/[1-9]?[0-9]/?', Foo)
```

I am against having them be e.g. `mydomain.tld/foo?n=84` only because I think it's a nice canonical(?) style to have permalinks without GET parameters.

I am currently doing:

```
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    #...
    def currentURL(self):
        return self.request.path_qs

class Foo(Handler):
    def get(self):
        n = re.match(r'.+/([1-9]?[0-9])/?', self.currentURL()).group(1)
        #do something with n
```

But is there a cleaner, less hacky method?

Comment: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html ... look at the very first block of code ... (the last example in that block)

Comment: What do you want the actual URLs to look like? `http://mydomain.tld/foo/n/84`? If there are multiple arguments, can they come in any order? Just showing the regexp you're using doesn't give us the rule you're intending if it's (by your own admission) hacky and ambiguous.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Oh wow, that's a neater solution than I anticipated! I'll accept answer if you post with example.

Comment: @abarnert They match the regex above, so like `http://mydomain.tld/foo/84`.

Comment: @OllieFord: Many things match the regex above. You really want to match anything ending with a number no matter what, and treat that number as the `n` argument to some particular API?

Comment: @abarnet No, the `WSGIApplication` class assumes the domain, and so I match `foo/n`, possibly with a trailing slash after it. If you are talking about the `re.match` in `Foo`, what comes before that is guaranteed to be `mydomain.tld/foo`, I skipped it for brevity, and to allow the domain/www/http/s to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html  ... I think the following will work

```
(r'foo/([1-9]?[0-9])/?', Foo)
```

then

```
class Foo(Handler):
    def get(self,n):
        print n
```